# Google Charts: hi is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

The past few days I have been trying to execute my Google Charts webpage ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1zpuuuw/1/)), but it seems like the error keeps changing, even when I didn't do anything different except refresh the webpage. I have tried using Chrome's "Empty Cache and hard reload" function, but that doesn't change anything. The errors I have been getting include things like `Uncaught typeError: hi is not a function`. I know this code works, because I was using it yesterday and it worked just fine. I changed nothing in my code between the time it worked and now. Am I importing something incorrectly, or is there something wrong with the Google Charts API. I get the same issue whenever I try to open [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter)

javascript:

```
google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['controls','corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

function drawDashboard(){
    var dataSet = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [{label:'date',type:'datetime'},{label:'Bytes from network:Bytes to network',type:'number'}],
        [new Date(2016,01,23,00,00),1.0],
        [new Date(2016,01,23,01,00),1.0075187969924813],
        [new Date(2016,01,23,03,00),1.126865671641791],
        [new Date(2016,01,24,22,00),0.987012987012987],
        [new Date(2016,01,25,01,00),1.0],
        [new Date(2016,01,25,02,00),0.9166666666666666],
        [new Date(2016,01,25,10,00),1.0],
        [new Date(2016,01,26,12,00),1.0],
        [new Date(2016,01,27,17,00),0.9864864864864865],
        [new Date(2016,01,28,22,00),0.03125],
        [new Date(2016,02,01,22,00),0.97],
    ]);

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    var dateRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({'controlType':'ChartRangeFilter',
                                                                   'containerId':'filter_div',
                                                                   'options':{
                                                                       'filterColumnLabel':'date',
                                                                       'ui':{
                                                                           'chartOptions':{
                                                                               'chartArea':{
                                                                                   'width':'90%'
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                   });

    var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({'chartType':'LineChart',
                                                           'containerId':'curve_chart',
                                                           'options':{
                                                               'title': 'Total Bytes from the Source Network to Total Bytes To the Source Network per Day',
                                                               'curveType': 'function',
                                                               'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '90%'},
                                                               'legend': 'none'
                                                           }
                                                          });

    dashboard.bind(dateRangeFilter,lineChart);

    dashboard.draw(dataSet);
}
```

html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //javascript code from above
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Data for this IP network</h1>
        <hr />
        <a href="../index.html">&lt&ltBACK TO INDEX</a>
        <div id="dashboard_div">
            <div id="curve_chart"></div>
            <div id="filter_div"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
#dashboard_div{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:10px;
}
#curve_chart{
    width:915px;
    height:300px;
}
#filter_div{
    width:915px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to caching and redirects used by the loader mechanism. A new release was pushed by the Google Visualization Team, and it broke a lot of people. Fixing to version 43 or 44 instead of using 'current' in your loader call should fix the issue for now.

See https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2185

Comment: I just changed `google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['controls','corechart']});` to `google.charts.load('44',{'packages':['controls','corechart']});` and it works now. Thanks for the help!